# Function to return cell references (addresses) of N highest values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am making a spreadsheet to track election results and return the elected representatives. We are using a system of proportional representation, applying the [modified Sainte-Laguë method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webster/Sainte-Lagu%C3%AB_method#Modified_Sainte-Lagu%C3%AB_method). The election results are being fed into a spreadsheet, and then divided by a given number (1.4, 3, 5, etc., up to 15 for a total of eight quotients, as mandated by the applicable law) to get the quotient from which to distribute the seats. Using conditional formatting, the spreadsheet now highlights the eight highest numbers, showing who get what position. This all works as intended.

We need to a) return a list of the eight successful candidates, and b) have that list return the cell reference (e.g., D7), rather than the number. I have played around with using the `LARGE` function, and am successfully returning the eight top quotients in C24:C31 using a formula that is, essentially, `=LARGE($C$2:$J$21, ROW()-23)`. I am not, however, able to get it to return the grid coordinates for these quotients.

The screenshot below shows a mock-up of what I want to achieve. The cells highlighted in green are highlighted as a result of conditional formatting;
they are the eight largest values in C2:J21. The cells highlighted in yellow are what I want to achieve. To be clear; the data in cell reference C2:J5 are generated by a formula, likewise the values in C24:C31 are the same eight values that are highlighted in green, above; they are formula generated. The hidden rows 6 through 21 are essentially duplicates of rows 1 through 5. I have uploaded the spreadsheet to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b1uVYwVasfr-1OYpw7_b4LTdNaF2105Y/view)

[image: Screenshot of the spreadsheet in question]

Comment: By "grid coordinate", do you mean cell reference?

Comment: please add some sample data with desired results, without that it's nearly impossible to suggest a working solution.

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Does that edit help? The table is correct, though the data is mocked up, as the election is a ways of as yet. I have uploaded the spreadsheet to Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b1uVYwVasfr-1OYpw7_b4LTdNaF2105Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So,  have you had a chance to look at my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I've been offline since posting my last update. I'll get down to it this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky. 
We can use

```
=MIN(IF($C$2:$J$21=value, ROW($C$2:$J$21)))
```

to find the number of the first row in which *`value`* appears. 
Likewise,

```
=MIN(IF($C$2:$J$21=value, COLUMN($C$2:$J$21)))
```

finds the number of the first column in which *`value`* appears. 
The above are array formulas.

*If the top eight values in `C2:J21` are unique,*
we can use the above to find a value in that grid. 
Then

```
INDEX($A$1:$J$21, row_number, column_number)
```

will index that cell,
and we can use

```
CELL("address", INDEX(the above))
```

to get the row & column address of that cell.

So, enter

```
=CELL("address", INDEX($A$1:$J$21, MIN(IF($C$2:$J$21=C24,ROW($C$2:$J$21))), MIN(IF($C$2:$J$21=C24,COLUMN($C$2:$J$21)))))
```

into cell `B24`,
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>,
and drag/fill down to `B31`.

Notes:

- `CELL("address", …)` returns an absolute address (with dollar signs).
  If you don’t want them, you can use

  ```
  =SUBSTITUTE(CELL(blah blah blah), "$", "")
  ```
- This does not handle duplicate values well. 
  For example, if `E3` also contained 8 (in addition to `D4`),
  it will report that they are both in `D3` (first row and first column). 
  This may be very hard to fix, but it would be possible to *test*
  whether such a coincidence had occurred, to allow manual correction.
- While this can be done all in one cell,
  it might simplify your life in the long run
  if you use helper columns for the row and column values.

This answer is based partly on a trick from [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/482057/150988#482059) by barry houdini.